# How do I disable unity's window animations while alt-tabbing?

Tags: unity, configuration

Right now, when I alt-tab repeatedly, it shrinks and grows windows dynamically.  Is there a way to turn this off?

I've poked around in system settings and `unity-tweak-tool` to no avail.

I'm on unity 7.4.5, Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, installed a few days ago.